# How to use 12" MacBook with 49 inch super UltraWide (32:9) display?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, resolution

I would like my MacBook to use the maximum resolution of my display at the correct aspect ratio. However, in system preferences this is not offered (see picture).

The resolution of my display is 5120 x 1440. While maximum vertical and horizontal resolutions offered by my MacBook are both greater (see picture), being 6720 x 3780. However this is the wrong aspect ratio.

1. Is there a way to make a custom aspect ratio (of 32:9)?
2. Is total pixel count the only thing that matters, or do aspect ratios also require individual support?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean MacBook or MacBook Pro?  There's no 12" MacBook Pro; your tag and titles don't match so assuming you mean 12" MacBook...looking at the specs of the 2017 model (latest) the highest resolution is 4096x2304.  So, it can't do what your asking.  Can you please confirm/clarify your question because what you're referring to doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, 12 inch MacBook.

Comment: In system preferences it shows a resolution greater than, what you suggested. However, is it possible to set a resolution of 4096x1440 then?

Comment: I can’t speak to why you’re seeing what you’re seeing in System Preferences but the max resolution is what it is.  The only thing I can think of is that you have an issue with the EDID data coming from the LG monitor.  They are notorious for this.  I would give their support a call and see what they recommend.

Comment: I think it’s to do with the fact my monitor is using usb-c. So the bandwidth is higher than what Apple expected in 2017. Because I assure you what in system preferences is not an error. When I click on the resolution of 6720x3780 it works. Also I’ve been able to get the correct resolution of 5120x1440 when I installed bootcamp on the MacBook, and kept the connection the same.

Comment: My question essentially is then, how can I set the horizontal and vertical pixels manually?